# How to implement visitor Design Pattern for Deleteing child Tables

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have Master Table

```
CALC_Master
```

Here CALC_Id is the common column for the Master  table

So I have Many child tables which will refer the above  Master table.Tables like CALC_name,CALC_Plan Like that etc...

Now I just need to filter the master table records  based on the below condition

```
select * from CALC_Master 
where STATUS_VALUE='COMP' 
      and CREATED_DATE < DateAdd(yy, -1, GetDate()) 
      and IS_CREATED_FROM_MSS_FLAG='Y'
```

So  based on the CALC_id return from the above table I need to delete all those records in their child tables.

So how do we implement this using Visitor Pattern

Already I have created objects of all tables like below

`CalcWiz delewiz = new CalcWiz();`

Comment: Do you need to implement this in your business logic, or can you implement it in the database?

Comment: Ya need it in Business logic not in Database

Answer (score 0):

Visitor Pattern is pattern of GOF, is applied on C# class, so you must define your Business Layer before define your pattern.

Here you can find class diagram and sample of code http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx

Comment: Ya I have defined all tables in terms of  objects.Just need to know how can delete the child table records based on the CALC_id returns from the query

Comment: Means just I need the structure of implement to delete

Answer (score 0):

If you're strictly following the visitor pattern, this is how I would implement it. However, not too fond of it, as I like my models/entities clean, and this would mean implementing ICalcEntity and flagging each of your domain models/entities with a Delete method, which strictly speaking, is a business logic class's responsibility.

```
public interface ICalcEntity
{
    void Delete(ICalcRepo repo);
}

public interface ICalcRepo
{
    void Delete(CALC_Master cMaster);
    void Delete(CALC_plan cPlan);
}

public class CalcRepo : ICalcRepo
{
    public void Delete(CALC_Master cMaster)
    {
        //delete CALC_Master where CALC_Id == cMaster.CALC_Id
    }

    public void Delete(CALC_plan cPlan)
    {
        //delete
    }
}

public class CALC_plan : ICalcEntity
{
    public void Delete(ICalcRepo repo)
    {
        repo.Delete(this);
    }
}

public class CALC_Master : ICalcEntity
{
    public int CALC_Id { get; set; }
    public List<ICalcEntity> Children { get; set; }

    public void Delete(ICalcRepo repo)
    {
        Children.ForEach(c => c.Delete(repo));
        repo.Delete(this);
    }
}
```